# How to handle vulcan response from Bash Script

Tags: bash, vulcan

Say I write a bash script to do this

```
#!/bin/bash
vulcan build -v -s .-c "./configure --enable-static etc.. etc..
```

The output of this command includes

```
->> Downloading build artifacts to
(available at http://myapp.herokuapp.com/{guid}
```

How would I parse this response that displays on the terminal to capture this url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var="->> Downloading build artifacts to
(available at http://myapp.herokuapp.com/{guid}" 

echo ${var#*available at }
```

Output:

```
http://myapp.herokuapp.com/{guid}
```

To capture output of the command into variable `var`:

```
var=$(vulcan build -v -s .-c "./configure --enable-static etc.. etc..)
```

Which is basically:

```
var=$(yourcommand)
```

See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) for more info about Parameter Expansion and Command Substitution.